# get id inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I working on a script that is made with plain javascript

```
parent.*nameofiframe*.document.getElementById('error').value;
```

I trying to do the same with jquery, but this is not working:

```
$('*nameofiframe*', window.parent.document).('#error').val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//get iframe in parent window:
var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementsByName(iframeName)[0];


//get value of element inside of iframe window
iframe.document.getElementById('error').value;
```

by the way, to run jquery inside of the parent window, you need to access the parent window's jquery object.

```
window.parent.$()
```

not

```
$(window.parent)
```

Comment: But how do I get the value with jquery?

Comment: Ohh did't noticed that "document"  what part of "getElementById" function.